# Why doesn't Symbol.toPrimitive work in JS Set?

Tags: javascript

I have a code but it doesn't work. Why doesn't it work although new Set is an object. Or does `Symbol.toPrimitive()` work only with objects created with `{}`, `Object.create()` etc?

```js
const obj = new Set(['a', 'b', 'c'])

obj[Symbol.toPrimitive] = function(hint) {
  if (hint == 'string') return 'string'
}

console.log('String:', obj)
```

Comment: `console.log()` doesn't call `@@toPrimitive`

Comment: There has to be a dupetarget for this. As @VLAZ said, depending on your environment, `console.log` probably doesn't call any of the methods that would trigger `@@toPrimitive`. Consoles generally render their own representation of the object instead. If you did `console.log('String: ' + obj)` instead, it would trigger it (with `hint = "default"`) and your function would (implicitly) return `undefined`.